# Laravel Model accessing a value of an instance of its self

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've got a model and the model its self could be linked to multiple other databases but only one at a time.

Instead of having a eloquent method for all the possible databases; it could have one that will use a variable from the self instance to choose the database and return just that.

It will save alot of work, as returning each one and testing to see if there are any results is cumbersome.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Feature extends Model
{
/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'companies';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'db_name',
        'enabled',
    ];


    /**
     * Uses the its own database name to determine which input to return.
     */
    public function inputs() {
       // if this->hidden->db_name == 'input type 1'
           // return $this->HasMany(InputType1::class);
       .... and so on
    } // end function inputs

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a strange behaviour but I think you can achieve what you are looking for like so :

```
//in your model
public function inputs()
{
    switch ($this->attributes['db_name']) {
        case : 'input type 1':
        return $this->hasMany(InputType1::class);
        case : //some other database name
        return //another relation
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything incorrect about it, or just strange? The db_name will never be set by user input.

Comment: That also doesn't seem to work, how can i access the instance variable of hidden->db_name

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on shempognon answer, what I actually got to work was

```
switch($this->db_name) {
     case 'Input_Timesheet':
      return $this->hasMany(Input_type1::class);
}
```